# Selenium Chrome Driver - SendKeys skipping symbols

Tags: google-chrome, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

We use Selenium Chrome Driver from C# .NET4 application. For some inputs it skips symbols sent with SendKeys function. But this problem exists on one computer and at the same time dissappears on other (the website with input is still the same). What can be problem about (using chrome last version 31.0.1650.63)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; in my case what caused it was the web page wasn't yet able to process the key strokes. When I gave the page a little more time to load, the problem went away.

To test if the problem you are experiencing is also caused by the page not being fully ready to process the key strokes, I recommend adding a sleep before the `SendKeys` command:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

If this improves the situation, you know that you have to add some extra waiting step before calling `SendKeys`.

Comment: sleep did not help ( any other suggestions ?

Comment: I'm getting this problem but most often with the *last* character. The first twenty-ish are fine.